# Linq2Sql: Random double-insert bug - a real poser

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, .net-4.0

OK, so you think you're a *real* debugger?  Try this one:

I've got a Linq2Sql project where suddenly we've discovered that occasionally, seemingly randomly, we get double-inserts of the same row.

I have subclassed `DataContext` and overridden `SubmitChanges`.  Inside there I have made a call to `GetChangeSet()`, both before and after the call to `base.SubmitChanges()`, and used a text file logger to record the objects in the `Inserts` collection.  Plus I hang on to a reference to the inserted objects long enough to record their autonumbered ID.

When the double-insert happens, I see in the DB that instead of one row each being inserted into `MyTableA` and `MyTableB`, there are two each.  SQL Profiler shows four insert statements, one after the other in rapid succession:

```
insert into MyTableA(...
insert into MyTableB(...
insert into MyTableA(...
insert into MyTableB(...
```

I check in the debug log, and there are only two objects in the `Inserts` collection: **one** of `MyClassA` and **one** of `MyClassB`.  After the call to `base.SubmitChanges()`, the changeset is empty (as it should be).  And the autonumber IDs show the **larger** value of the newly inserted rows.

Another piece of useful information: the bug **never** happens when stepping through in debug mode; only when you run without breakpoints.  This makes me suspect it's something to do with the speed of execution.

We have been using the same `DataContext` subclass for over a year now, and we've never seen this kind of behavior before in our product.  It only happens with `MyClassA` and `MyClassB`.

To summarize:

1. From the debug log, everything looks like it's working correctly.
2. On SQL Profiler, you can see that a double-insert is happening.
3. This behavior happens frequently but unpredictably, only to the two classes mentioned, excepting that it never happens when stepping through code in debug mode.

**EDIT - New information:**
Inside my `DataContext` subclass, I have the following code:

```
try {
  base.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode.ContinueOnConflict);
} catch (ChangeConflictException) {
  // Automerge database values for members that client has not modified.
  foreach (ObjectChangeConflict occ in ChangeConflicts) {
    occ.Resolve(RefreshMode.KeepChanges);
  }
}
// Submit succeeds on second try.
base.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode.FailOnFirstConflict);
```

`MyTableA` and `MyTableB` both have a mandatory foreign key `OtherTableID` referencing `OtherTable`.  The double insert happens when a `ChangeConflictException` happens during an update of the common parent table `OtherTable`.

We're on the scent, now...

Comment: Are there any triggers on the tables?

Comment: Are the tables linked together (with navigation properties in your L2S model)?

Comment: @Jan - no triggers, no connection between the tables other than that they are both "child" tables of the same parent table, i.e. both of them have a FK `OtherTableID` that points to `OtherTable.ID`

Comment: @Jan - no multithreading.  The logger shows it's the same thread all the way through.

Comment: Can you show some code? At least the SubmitChanges part and the part where you add the new objects.

Comment: @Jan - clue while debugging - see my edit

Comment: I am wondering if `occ.Resolve(RefreshMode.KeepChanges);` is doing a little more than we think. What happens if you comment out that second call to `base.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode.FailOnFirstConflict);`? Do you still get the double inserts?

Comment: @nick_w - if you don't call the 2nd SubmitChanges, nothing happens.  Since the first SubmitChanges threw an exception, nothing was persisted then, so without another SubmitChanges nothing else will be persisted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like it's a **BUG** in Linq2Sql!  Here's a repeatable experiment for you:

```
using (var db1 = new MyDataContext()) {
  var obj1 = db1.MyObjects.Single(x => x.ID == 1);
  obj1.Field1 = 123;
  obj1.RelatedThingies.Add(new RelatedThingy {
                           Field1 = 456,
                           Field2 = "def",
                           });
  using (var db2 = new MyDataContext()) {
    var obj2 = db2.MyObjects.Single(x => x.ID == 1);
    obj2.Field2 = "abc";
    db2.SubmitChanges();
  }
  try {
    db1.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode.ContinueOnConflict);
  } catch (ChangeConflictException) {
    foreach (ObjectChangeConflict occ in ChangeConflicts) {
      occ.Resolve(RefreshMode.KeepChanges);
    }
  }
  base.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode.FailOnFirstConflict);
}
```

Result: `MyObject` record with ID = 1 gets updated, Field1 value is 123 and Field2 value is "abc".  And there are **two** new, identical records inserted to RelatedThingy, with MyObjectID = 1, Field1 = 456 and Field2 = "def".

Explain **THAT!**

**UPDATE:** After logging this on Microsoft Connect, the nice folks at MS asked me to put together a little demo project highlighting the bug.  And wouldn't you know it - I couldn't reproduce it.  It seems to be connected to some weird idiosyncrasy of my project.  Don't have time to investigate further, and I found a workaround, anyway...

Comment: What is the state of the database after the first `db1.SubmitChanges` call? It should be unmodified because the transaction should have been rolled back. Can you confirm that?

Comment: @usr - No!  After the first db1.SubmitChanges, there's already a record in RelatedThingy!  Wow, what a shocker!

Comment: So maybe L2S does not rollback the transaction? That would be strange. I'll probably investigate this when I have time (might take month).

Answer (score 0):

When I've had a problem like this before it is usually down to multiple threads executing the same code at the same time.

Have you tried using the **lock{}** command to make sure the insert is only being used by a single thread? 
[MSDN Lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thought of that.  I'm logging the thread ID, too, and it's the same thread.  And the code is all inside a `lock{}` block.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, we recently found this problem with our retry logic for `SubmitChanges`.  We were doing an `InsertAllOnSubmit`. When a `ChangeConflictException` occurred, we would retry with a `Resolve(RefreshMode.KeepChanges,true)` on each `ObjectChangeConflict`.

We redid the work a different way (retry logic to re-perform the entire transaction) and that seems to fix the problem.